# Rails+MySQL on production: database configuration does not specify adapter (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I just faced this issue on the production server. The application was working long months, but now out of nothing appeared this error:

```
database configuration does not specify adapter (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)
```

and I don't know how to get rid of it. I double-checked the `database.yml` file, but there are no modifications. Tried to restart unicorn, but it didn't help too.

Where should I look further?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error before,

I tried to uninstall mysql2 and reintall it again using **gem install mysql2**,

using **bundle install** command with **gem 'mysql2'** in **GemFile** doesn't worked before.

Comment: Well, I did sort of the same - removed from the bundle the `mysql2` gem, `bundle update`, deploy -> error - missing gem. So I added the gem back, bundle, deploy - now everything works. If anyone would know what's behind this mystery, that would be great.

Comment: Did you ever find out?